# Why caddy + php-fpm configuration in docker-compose doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a development environment on my local machine which consists of caddy + PHP.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

    webserver:
        image: caddy
        container_name: webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/srv
            - ./docker/caddy/Caddyfile/:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: pingr
            MYSQL_DB: pingr
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pingr
            MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

Dockerfile for app service:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl intl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Caddyfile:

```
:80 {
    root * /srv/public
    php_fastcgi app:9000

    file_server /uploads/*
    encode gzip zstd
}
```

**This results in "File not found" when I open http://localhost.**

I'm 100% sure that the problem is because root in caddyfile and volumes in app and webserver serivces are different.

When I make them the same, looks like it works. Moreover, it even doesn't matter which path I choose, I can have `/var/bar` for example.

But then I don't understand how it works.

1. In caddy image they say that the working directory is `/srv`. So as I get it, this is where site files should be placed.
2. In the Caddyfile I specify that Caddy should look at `/srb/public` (because I use Laravel)..
3. In the php-fpm image, they say that the working directory is `/var/www`. Which means that.. I'm not sure what does it mean. If I don't use Docker, then in my local machine I'd have caddy + php, only caddy "knows" where the source .php files are located. In case the requests asks for a .php file Caddy proxies it to php. Maybe I don't need a volume here at all?

Comment: check after you run your docker port `3306` is running ? or not and check logs

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling understanding the same concept. I think that:

1. With your `Caddyfile` you say that the document root is `/srv`, so static files are served from that directory and you need to bind-mount you project (public) directory to the caddy service
2. When you request PHP files, Caddy will proxy the request to php-fpm unix socket or TCP/IP (the latter, in your case)
3. How php-fpm find out the source files? Caddy is passing `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (setted to `/srv`) and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (setted to `/srv/index.php`)

.. that's why you need to bind-mount you project public directory also to php service, but to `/srv` and not to  `/var/www`.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand here is how Caddy wraps `reverse_proxy` with their opinionated `php_fastcgi` directive explained here https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/php_fastcgi .

It assumes that Caddy has access to PHP files same as PHP-FPM and directory structure is the same.

To understand why, we need to look at this part of extended form:

```
...
    @indexFiles file {
        try_files {path} {path}/index.php index.php
        split_path .php
    }
    rewrite @indexFiles {file_match.relative}
...
```

`@indexFiles` is a labeled [file](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers#file) matcher in Caddy terms. The `try_files` part which checks in sequence if those files exist on **disk**. That's why if Caddy runs outside of PHP's app filesystem directory or on different server it won't work.

Simple answer to this problem would be to have same directory structure for Caddy and PHP-FPM and both having the same access to those files.

---

My personal view on this is that this wrapper assumes too much and gives too little ability to set fastcgi parameters directly as, for example, Nginx does.
They even give examples with FPM over network giving false hopes that Caddy doesn't require access to PHP files nor checks their existence. I lost hours understanding why Caddy does that and why my setup doesn't work.

I think that this wrapper was made for early `PHP 5` applications or **Wordpress** as most of the current apps has single `index.php` entry and any other option to access it. Which `php_fastcgi` fails to deliver properly.

In my experience is much better to use extender form and stay away from this shortcut.

For example, if we have single `index.php` in public directory we could use this:

```
    handle {
        root * /var/www/app/public
        rewrite index.php
        reverse_proxy unix//var/run/php/php8-fpm.sock {
            transport fastcgi {
                split .php
                capture_stderr
            }
        }
    }
```

This way FPM can run over socket or network and Caddy is not interested if those files exist. We set correct `root` path and requested file `index.php` so it can be correctly passed to our FPM server. This is sad as we need to trick Caddy rather than directly set correct parameters sent to FPM. In this example `/var/www/app/public` must be the same as the directory where our `index.php` file is where PHP-FPM runs as it receives requested directory and filename from Caddy to run.

Caddy is great software but sadly its support for PHP is too opinionated and over complicated IMHO.